# transpose function of numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to numpy and python and I am trying to understand the usage of transpose function of numpy. The code below works fine but I am still not be able to understand the effect of transpose function and also the use of the arguments inside it. It would be great help if someone can explain the usage and effect of transpose function in below code.

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [[[[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]], [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]],[[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]], [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]]], [[[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]], [[[1,0],[1,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]]]],[[[[1,0],[1,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]]], [[[1,0],[1,1]],[[1,0],[1,1]]]]]]
arr = np.array(my_list)
perm_testing = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
testing = arr.transpose(perm_testing)
print(testing)
```

**Edit**

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]
arr = np.array(my_list)

perm_testing = [1,0]
testing = arr.transpose(perm_testing)
print(testing)

[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
```

Comment: Here's a visual metaphor.  Picture you holding the matrix in your hand, with two fingers holding the upper left, and two fingers holding the lower right.  Now, flip it around 180 degrees.  That's a transpose.  What were rows become columns, and vice versa.  There is no transpose for 1-D arrays, so your example does nothing.  Try `perm_testing = [[0,1,2,3,4,5]]` instead.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts for your response. What is the use of 'perm_testing' argument in transpose because when I print testing, I get array contained in 'my_list'?

Comment: It's harder to understand with n-dimensional arrays when n>2, but it's the same principle. The 2nd argument specifies the order in which the axes of the original array are transposed. So [0,1,2,3,4,5] keeps the original order, and thus the original array. For a 2-dim array, array.transpose() is the same as array.transpose(1,0), which means inverts the axes, so invert rows and columns.

Comment: Why was https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html not sufficient for you to understand what it does?

Comment: Thank you @Swifty. I edited the question accordingly. Yes, I tested it for 2 D array, and it works but still not much clear about it for higher dimensions.

Comment: Thank you @mkrieger1 for the response. The snippet of the code of multidimensional array I was trying to understand had a little different syntax especially the argument of the transpose.

Comment: For 2d there are only orders.  [0,1] changes nothing.  [1,0] is the ordinary transpose.  For 3d and higher, there are more choices.  Make an array like `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`, and look at the variations - paying special attention to the shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt to visually explain for a 3d-array. I hope it'll help you better understand what's happening:

```
a=np.arange(24).reshape(2,4,3)

# array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#         [ 3,  4,  5],
#         [ 6,  7,  8],
#         [ 9, 10, 11]],
#
#        [[12, 13, 14],
#         [15, 16, 17],
#         [18, 19, 20],
#         [21, 22, 23]]])
```

And a visual 3d representation of a (axis 0 corresponds to the first bracket level and to the first size in the shape, and so on for axis 1 and 2):

[image: 3d array]

```
a.transpose(1,0,2)  # swapping axis 0 and 1

# array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#         [12, 13, 14]],
# 
#        [[ 3,  4,  5],
#         [15, 16, 17]],
# 
#        [[ 6,  7,  8],
#         [18, 19, 20]],
#
#        [[ 9, 10, 11],
#         [21, 22, 23]]])
```

Visual 3d representation of the new array (sorry, my drawing skills are quite limited):

[image: new array]

Comment: I am highly thankful to you @Swifty for explaining the concept in detail.